# Refactoring conditionals with polymorphism in dart

Tags: dart

I recently came across the title of this question while studying Dart Apprentice but I couldn't find anything related to the dart language. I understand how conditionals work and while I have a fair knowledge of OOP, I understand how polymorphism works. But I can't see the relationship between conditionals and polymorphism or how one can replace conditionals with polymorphism. Can anyone help clarify?

Comment: I think this will help to you: https://dev.to/mundim/refactoring-replacing-conditional-with-polymorphism-2ob6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that it means that instead of doing conditional checks on objects to decide what to do with them, as you typically would in a static helper function, you should instead rely on virtual method dispatch.

That means doing dynamic dispatch using the virtual method invocation functionality, instead of doing it manually using `is` tests.

Example:
Here we have an recursive data structure, representing JSON data.

```dart
abstract class JsonData {}

class JsonValue<T> extends JsonData {
  final T value;
  JsonValue(this.value);
}

class JsonList extends JsonData {
  final List<JsonData> _elements;
  JsonList(List<JsonData> elements) : _elements = elements;
  int get length => _elements.length;
  JsonData operator[](int index) => _elements[index];
}

class JsonMap extends JsonData {
  final Map<String, JsonData> _map;
  JsonMap(Map<String, JsonData> map) : _map = map;
  Iterable get keys => _map.keys;
  JsonData operator[](String key) => 
    _map[key] ?? (throw ArgumentError.value(key, "key", "No entry"));
}
```

An example object graph could be:

```dart
var data = JsonMap({
  "first": JsonList([JsonValue(1), JsonValue("ok")]),  
  "second": JsonValue(false),
});
```

Now, if I wanted to figure out whether a particular string occurs in the `JsonData`, either as a map key or as a value, I *could* write something like:

```dart
bool containsString(JsonData json, String text) {
  if (json is JsonValue) {
    return text == json.value;
  } else if (json is JsonList) {
    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      if (containsString(json[i], text)) return true;
    }
    return false;
  } else if (json is JsonMap) {
    for (var key in json.keys) {
      if (text == key) return true;
      if (containsString(json[key], text)) return true;
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    throw UnsupportedError("Unexpected JSON value");
  }
}
```

However, it is better to put the specialized functionality into the classes themselves, changing the classes to:

```dart
abstract class JsonData {
  bool containsString(String text);
}

class JsonValue<T> extends JsonData {
  final T value;
  JsonValue(this.value);
  bool containstString(String text) => text == value;
}

class JsonList extends JsonData {
  final List<JsonData> _elements;
  JsonList(List<JsonData> elements) : _elements = elements;
  int get length => _elements.length;
  JsonData operator[](int index) => _elements[index];
  bool containsString(String text) {
    for (var element in elements) {
      if (element.containsString(text)) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

class JsonMap extends JsonData {
  final Map<String, JsonData> _map;
  JsonMap(Map<String, JsonData> map) : _map = map;
  Iterable get keys => _map.keys;
  JsonData operator[](String key) => 
    _map[key] ?? (throw ArgumentError.value(key, "key", "No entry"));
  bool containsString(String text) {
    for (var entry in _map.entries) {
      if (text == entry.key || entry.value.containsString(text)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Using this approach is better for a number of reasons:

- It puts the functionality near the data it works on. The individual methods can access the private state of the object, not just the public API.
- It makes it easier to add more classes to the data-type. It's clear which functionality must be implemented, and you can't forget a case in a static helper function somewhere.
- The individual methods are smaller and easier to understand.